# To speed up firefox, is disabling unwanted add-ons enough or should I remove them completely?

Tags: firefox, browser-addons, speed, firefox-extensions

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Do disabled Firefox extensions make Firefox slower?](https://superuser.com/questions/30805/do-disabled-firefox-extensions-make-firefox-slower)

In case 'it depends on the type of extension': Ones in my disabled list include DownThemAll, DownloadHelper, DivX Plus web player, Adobe Acrobat create pdf, and Adobe Contribute toolbar.

Comment: The answer may depend on whether you are trying to speed up initial application load, screen rendering, or something else.

Comment: @frenchglen: What have you tried? What do you consider a speed up?

Comment: @JRobert: For speed, it's more just general use once firefox has loaded.

Comment: @TomWijsman: don't want to uninstall anything that may be useful in future, so this is why I want to check whether I should uninstall due to noticeable speed improvements, or just leave them as disabled.

Comment: @frenchglen: Huh? But you said unwanted? I actually think you would not need any of those. You didn't answer my questions, because `speed` is kinda broad...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Disabling extensions is enough - a disabled extension is as good as not present. There is still a small startup delay due to that extension being in the database but it is absolutely negligible (I tried measuring it once but it is way below the usual startup time variance on my system).

Comment: Thanks, that's the answer I was looking for :). If it only means startup delay that's fine and I'll keep em juuust in case I need em! Cheers for that,